# PL/SQL EXCEPTION BLOCK Not working

Tags: sql, exception, plsql

I have the following procedure with an exception block.  When I execute this procedure the system is catching the error instead of my exception block.  Anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong. Thanks

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_ORDER
       (CUST_NUM IN CUSTOMERS_T_P2.CNO%TYPE,
       EMP_NUM IN EMPLOYEE_T_P2.ENO%TYPE,
       REC_DATE IN  ORDERS_T_P2.RECEIVED%TYPE)
     IS
     BEGIN
     IF REC_DATE IS NULL THEN
       INSERT INTO ORDERS_T_P2 (ONO, CNO, ENO, RECEIVED)
        VALUES
          (ORDER_NUMBER_SEQ.NEXTVAL, CUST_NUM, EMP_NUM, SYSDATE);
     ELSE 
        INSERT INTO ORDERS_T_P2 (ONO, CNO, ENO, RECEIVED)
          VALUES
           (ORDER_NUMBER_SEQ.NEXTVAL, CUST_NUM, EMP_NUM, REC_DATE);
     END IF;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
       ROLLBACK WORK;
         INSERT INTO ORDER_ERRORS_T_P2 
          VALUES
          (ORDER_NUMBER_SEQ.NEXTVAL, SYSDATE, 'STRING WAS ENTERED INSTEAD OF NUMBER');
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STRING WAS ENTERED INSTEAD OF NUMBER');
       END;
```

Comment: Maybe it isn't a value error?

Comment: it doesn't work for any error I put in even a When Others error

Comment: Put the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE immediately after the ROLLBACK.  And please edit your message and include the exact message text.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but what do you mean by exact message text?

Comment: Put the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE immediately after the ROLLBACK. And this is the error I get BEGIN ADD_ORDER('BROOKE', 1234, '1-JAN-13'); END;

*

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: maybe you need to insert `COMMIT` after `INSERT INTO ORDER_ERRORS_T_P2 `

Answer (score 0):

VALUE_ERROR Should be declared as Exception in DECLARE block

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_ORDER
       (CUST_NUM IN CUSTOMERS_T_P2.CNO%TYPE,
       EMP_NUM IN EMPLOYEE_T_P2.ENO%TYPE,
       REC_DATE IN  ORDERS_T_P2.RECEIVED%TYPE)
     IS
VALUE_ERROR EXCEPTION;

     BEGIN
---------------
```